# Raspberry pi 4 Model B green light is consistently glowing when power is given

Tags: boot-issues, board-leds, act

It was working fine and i shut it of and all of a sudden its blank the power light is lit which is a good sign but the act(green) light is lit too its not blinking which is not good. Tried every possible thing but of no use. Green light isnt blinking its solid on

I tried reloading the raspian from the pi imager. Tried to boot from usb. updated bootloader settings.
but the green light is stucked with power light not blinked once.

Comment: Could you report the result of each step you took in the [boot sticky](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151)?

Comment: why are you asking about the light? ... if the RPi does not boot, ask about booting problems ... the light is just a symptom, it is not the problem

Comment: Im a begginer to pi and whatever i know is from internet resource and that is green constant light is light of death in Rpi 4. This happened with number of peoples. 
moreover i need to tell this that i have an improvement with my Rpi 4 i was holding it in hand so my fingers were griped around microprocessor i notices that the act light blinked twice or thrice when the microcontroller is pressed. As the green light never blinked from few days

Comment: Can it be a hardware issue

Comment: All the boot sticky results in nothing. There was no sign of light in Rpi no display no blinking led as if it was receiving power and is paralyzed